# What kind of this HTML text?

Tags: html

I stumped on this website with some strange text. The format was kept when I copied and I could not get rid of them. Even when I create a folder and pasted the text as folder name, the format was still there.

[image]

I also tried with JS, didn't work either.

[image]

What is this? How can I produce it with html?

Comment: Hello, coukd you please orovide information about what is it that you are copying, or a visual plus a code, example of the source? (Ctrl+ U) in the website.

Comment: Unicode has code-points for alternative Latin characters, like Mathematical symbols, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols

Comment: Please post the results of `temp0.textContent.codePointAt(0)` and  `temp0.textContent.codePointAt(1)`

Comment: The symbols seem to be the Unicode Serif Bold mathematical characters, fwiw.

Comment: @Dai temp0.textContent.codePointAt(0) = 119822 and temp0.textContent.codePointAt(1) = 56334

Comment: `119822` is `0x00_01_D4_0E` which is Unicode code-point `U+1D40E` aka "" which is listed in [the Unicode Mathematical Alphanumeric symbols tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols) - _mystery solved_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symbols displayed on webpages, and in any other text in computing, are represented as positions in a character set. Today, this is most commonly Unicode.

For example:

- `a` is `U+0061 : LATIN SMALL LETTER A`
- `&` is `U+0026 : AMPERSAND {and}`
- is `U+1F631 : FACE SCREAMING IN FEAR`

The characters you are looking at are [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols).

- is `U+1D468 : MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL A`

They are designed for use in formulas and the like when writing about maths and science.

Due to the history of maths and science, they look like regular letters, sometimes with specific formatting.

However, they are **not** regular letters and while using them like that will **look** cute for people reading the webpage they will cause major accessibility problems when they interact with (for example) screen readers and search engine indexing robots.

Kent C. Dodds has a [video demonstrating the problem](https://twitter.com/kentcdodds/status/1083073242330361856) which I highly recommend.

While you can generate them (e.g. by copy/pasting them from somewhere that uses them, or writing a program that outputs something based on its code point) you should not (see above). Use CSS to format your text instead.

Comment: Google _seems_ to index those characters as homoglyphs of normal Latin characters, but yeah, VoiceOver keels-over, just like in the video.

Comment: The OP just confirmed that the first character is `U+1D40E` = "", so _mystery solved!_